# jQuery regex to find string by substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web, replace

On my website I have multiple occurrences of a string with always the same substring (let's say "boo-foo", "loo-foo" and "great-foo").

I want to replace all of those with **firstpart-**foo.
So the first part of all those should be bold.

Can anyone provide a regex for that in jQuery?

I believe it should look something like this, but with regex:

```
$(this).html($(this).html.replace("boo-foo","<strong>boo-</strong>foo"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this script,

```
var htmlText = $('body').html();
var replaced = htmlText.replace(/([\w\d]+)\-foo/ig, "<strong>$1</strong>-foo");
$('body').html(replaced);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6doa4o6/

Updated Fiddle to make "-" bold as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/o6doa4o6/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/^(.*)\-foo$/ig,'<strong>$1</strong>-foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **back Reference** to look for the captured group and then use the `string.replace` method to replace the string using a Regex. Backreferences allows to reference the text which was previously matched by a capturing group. In javascript you can make use of `$1` to reference the first captured group. Similarly `$2, $3..` for each captured group.

Following implementation shows this behavior, excluding the Jquery part.

```js
var stringValue = `boo-foo
loo-foo
great-foo`;

var regexToSearch = /([a-zA-Z]*)-foo/g;

var result = stringValue.replace(regexToSearch, '<strong>$1</strong>-foo');
console.log(result);
```